# Best approach to use MongoDB with SocketIO per user connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I have an API created with Socket.IO 4.

This API every time it starts it makes a connection to MongoDB using Mongoose.
This connection remains open until the script exits.

This use of Mongoose ​​creates the Models and Schemas on every startup.

Every time a user connects to the Socket.IO server, it uses this open connection to MongoDB to save that user's data into MongoDB.
When there is a disconnection, this data is deleted, using the connection opened there at the beginning of the script.

Is my approach incorrect or correct?

My fear is that a hundred users connect at the same time and the execution of the script takes time to execute each save/delete one at a time.

Or should I for each request open a connection to MongoDB, do what needs to be done and close the connection (another fear: overloading with MongoDB)?

** *I already noticed that even making a connection, there are always 5 connections in MongoDB that were established with the origin in the IP of the Socket.IO server.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely fine. This is the way it should be done, connections to database should be per app basis.

For example: your PHP server makes a connection to the database and it caches the connection, whenever a script needs to be run, it provides that cached database connection. Single connection persists in cache and is shared to future script runs or requests.

If you ever used Express.js or other back-end libraries built with node.js, python or other languages, they always initialize a database connection at the start of your application and this connection is used to handle every request.

If you would create a new connection to database for each websocket session, you would possibly slow down both your application and database since database connections are expensive tasks.